# bootstrap-mutliselect data-actions-box="true" set and not working

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using bootstrap & came to a point where I added the data-actions-box option.

```
<select id="sex" name="sex[]" multiple data-actions-box="true">
<option value="1" >Woman</option>
<option value="2" >Man</option>
</select>
```

However the actionsBox is not appearing. Thanks for your help.

**THERE ARE TWO similarly named plugins as pointed out in Answer provided.**

If you use bootstrap-multiselect, use this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sex").multiselect({ includeSelectAllOption:true }); 
});
</script>

<select id="sex" name="sex[]" multiple data-actions-box="true">
  <option value="1" >Woman</option>
  <option value="2" >Man</option>
</select>
```

it adds a Select All option to pulldown...

Comment: The actionBox is a [Select All | Deselect All ]  inset on top of the scroll-down

Comment: can u post code of you full page? Also r u sure there no js error?

Comment: Company policy forbids pasting actual full code :( $("#sex").multiselect({buttonWidth: "200px",         
                                            actionsBox: true,
                                            selectAllText: "All",
                                            deselectAllText: "None"});

Comment: As you see I am passing initialization params to multiselectand setting actionsBox = true

Comment: Also - No JS errors - it is passing all and still not working

Comment: It looks to me u are mixing among these two bootstrap plugins.https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect    and http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/. Because data-actions-box="true" is an attribute for bootstrap-select where u have multiselect option with buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me u are mixing among these two bootstrap https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect and https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select. Because `data-actions-box="true"` is an attribute for `bootstrap-select` where you have multiselect option with buttons.

Check this example.
http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#multiple-select-boxes

Comment: I need new glasses and stronger coffee - thank you - I will opt for a dding a clickable div in the section of options lists that clears them all in one shot ---- THANK YOU so much....